# Component Attribute to load file c#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I created a custom Component, and now I'm trying to use [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx) for the Properties that show up on the Properties Panel.

I tried to use a file dialog to make it easier to load one Filepath for a Property

```
    [Browsable(true), DefaultValue(@"Firmware\fx3.img"), Description("Specifies the the location of the Firmware file.")]
    [EditorAttribute(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public string FwFile
    {
        get { return fwfile; }
        set
        {
            fwfile = value;
        }
    }
```

With this approach it gives me the absolute path, which can't be used.

The files I want to load are embedded resources, and are being copied to the output directory under this path for example "Firmware\fx3.img" (relative to output directory). 
This can change, that is why I want to select the file explicitly.

Is there a better way to do this than writing down the relative path?

Comment: It can change, but is it always .\Firmware\fx3.img ? Just qualify it with the .\

Comment: Filename can be for example fx3v2.img. Something can be incremented to add a version number for example or really changing the name. The Component is supposed to be used by other people.

Comment: The file should be added to the project and referenced in the Property..

Comment: Seems like a candidate for configuration, .ini file, registry key.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the FileNameEditor class so that its result conforms to what you're trying to do:

```
    public class MyFileNameEditor : System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor
    {
        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            var fullname = base.EditValue(context, provider, value);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullname)){
                /// modify Fullname here to return relative path
            }
            return fullname;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So the idea was to transform the path into a relative one.. should be ok :)